# Possible SVG Path Chrome Bug

Tags: google-chrome, svg, raphael

I'm experiencing a possible bug with the path element in Chrome. I have copy/pasted what RaphaelJS has rendered here: http://petesaia.com/work/svg-chrome-bug/

### In Safari & Firefox

[image]
<sub>(source: [petesaia.com](http://petesaia.com/work/svg-chrome-bug/safari.png))</sub>

### In Chrome (19.0.1084.46)

[image]
<sub>(source: [petesaia.com](http://petesaia.com/work/svg-chrome-bug/chrome.png))</sub>

Obviously there are very many points in this file which is why I limited 50 points per path element. As you can see, 2 paths are missing from the right side and 2 very small paths are missing from the left side. I found one of the paths that is not displaying and singled it out. You can see that here: http://petesaia.com/work/svg-chrome-bug/singled.html

You will notice that even when the path is singled out it still doesn't show. So Chrome must dislike something with that path.

I also noticed that *sometimes* it displays correctly, usually when I open and close the javascript console. It's very flimsy. I've experimented with changing stroke and weight and also no luck.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

**New discovery:** These x/y values are the coordinates that break the single.html sample: 620.3536711111101,232.16932207146056  I know this because when you truncate the path up to that point it works perfectly. However, I still have no idea as to why they would break it.

Thanks,
Pete

PS: I do plan on simplifying the shape(s) but this has caught my attention first.

Comment: I can confirm that the path does display in Safari and Illustrator, but not in Chrome v19 on OS X.

Comment: You should file a bug, http://crbug.com/new it is a better place than asking it here :)